# PHP extension CLI crashing

Tags: php, c++

I have c++ class used for encrypting a file - works fine on it's own.  I wrapped it using swig for 5.6.x-nts-Win32-x64 PHP.  Usage:

```
<?php

require("crypt.php");

$e = new CCrypt();

//(plain, encrypted)
if ($e->EncryptFile("sample","enc/sample")) {
  print "Encrypted file\n";
}
$e = NULL;
print "Goodbye\n"
?>
```

Problem is this seems to work *sometimes*, with no consistent line in the extension code as to where it crashes when debugging.  Error is corrupted heap.  I am new to developing PHP extensions, and I'm wondering if this has to do with unsupported 64-bit PHP version, or something unique to CLI.  Swig does not (yet) support PHP 7 :/

**UPDATE**
Forgot to mention encryption works fine if run as an executable from PHP.

Comment: the php code by itself is essentially useless, since the crash would be occuring inside your plugin. Since you've provided none of that code, we can't help you.

Comment: Only supplied it to give an idea of what it's basically used for.  Extension code is too vast to include here and is proprietary, but I understand.  I can at most give a link to the interface wrapper code generated by swig if that would help, but it's long and ugly.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) The point is to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it reproducible so that SO users can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be my lack of understanding SWIG's implementation of STL.  When I removed STL from the wrapper source, the extension worked as expected.  I later added STL back in, albeit in proper SWIG fashion!